# Client-side forms in ASP.NET Core (Modals, etc.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there an approach to implementing client-side forms (particularly in a modal dialog on the client-side) that meets the following criteria in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

1. Takes advantage of the attributes on the model. I do not want to define validation in multiple places.
2. Uses the standard way of building forms (i.e. `<input asp-for="...">`). I do not want to build forms different just because they're in a floating `<div>`.
3. Does not use an `<iframe>`. I do not want to load an entirely new page with CSS/JS, etc.
4. Performs client-side validation. This should work automatically as it does with the default tag helpers (using unobtrusive validation).
5. Does not require manually posting data to the server. (i.e. the submit button automatically does an XHR). I do not want to handle this manually, ideally it should be handled out of the box.

The only approach I've found that checks all of the boxes is to use a combination of a partial view and the unobtrusive ajax JS library. This works OK, but is it the recommended approach for building new applications? It's not included in any of the default template projects, and it does not seem to be widely discussed in the context of ASP.NET Core. I have found one instance where it is discussed (https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/) but the framing of that blog post is one of porting legacy applications.

Comment: What problem are you having with razor views? You define the form in HTML and make it hidden and show it as floating window on click. Nothing to do with ASP.NET Core per se.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If you want to do so with help of asp.net core then you have to go with returning partial view from the controller method and catching it in ajax success function and then bind the return view to the modal..

**But this is not recommended option..**

**Best option is to use Client Side Framework like AngularJs, Angular 5 etc with server side api..Angular 5 will fulfill your requirement so easily..So you should go with Angular 5 and ASP.NET Core Web API..**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The challenge is that, imagine you have an application that is 95% full page forms, and you have a minor corner case of 2-3 small dialogs with 1-2 form fields in them. Bringing in a huge SPA framework (both in data size and the associated spectrum of technical knowledge) to address that concern seems a bit much.